# Add SSRS project created in BIDS to MVC3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, reporting-services, webforms, ssrs-2008

I have created SSRS project in BIDS and I want to use the reports in this project in MVC3 application.

Do I need to publish the SSRS project? I know that I need to add .aspx files in my MVC3 project to use the ReportViewer control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you do need to publish your reports to the report manager.

Once the reports are published, you can use a component to access and display them on you page.
Something like this:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="100%" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)"  ProcessingMode="Remote" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%">
    <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="http://localhost:8080/ReportServer" Timeout="-1" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to publish the report to a web hosting and the sql server is shared and used by a lot of users, so the hosting administrator told me that he can't give me the username and password that are required by the publishinp process. Is there a way to add the report in VS2010 and use ReportViewer there?

Comment: you need to publish the report to your SSRS report manager, otherwise you wont be able to run it